# How do I setup different app icons for ios 6 and ios 7 devices using air 3.9?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, air, ios7

I need to have two differnet icon graphics for ios 6 and and ios 7 devices. The problem is that ios 7 still uses 29x29 and 58x58 icons for both ios 7 and 6. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

if you have update your SDK then,

```
    <image16x16></image16x16>
    <image29x29></image29x29>
<image32x32></image32x32>
<image36x36></image36x36>
<image40x40></image40x40>
<image48x48></image48x48>
<image50x50></image50x50>
<image57x57></image57x57>
<image58x58></image58x58>
<image72x72></image72x72>
<image76x76></image76x76>
<image80x80></image80x80>
<image96x96></image96x96>
<image100x100></image100x100>
<image114x114></image114x114>
<image120x120></image120x120>
<image128x128></image128x128>
<image144x144></image144x144>
<image152x152></image152x152>
<image512x512></image512x512>
<image732x412></image732x412>
<image1024x1024></image1024x1024>
```

29X29 and 58X58 size for icon is will be available.

~ cheers